# MQTT Broker in application?

Tags: java, mqtt

I've been using mosquitto for several months now, but now I've got to the point that I'd like to build a standalone broker into my Java application.  Is it possible to do this, or would I need to have to have mosquitto running by itself on a server?

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to create a JNI wrapper around mosquitto, but you may do better looking at one of the other broker implementations, specifically one already written in java.

There are several listed on the mqtt.org server wiki page.

https://github.com/mqtt/mqtt.github.io/wiki/servers

e.g. Moquette, HiveMQ or ActiveMQ

Comment: Thanks!  I've been playing with moquette for a bit, and it appears to be what I want, but I can't seem to find any documentation :|

Comment: Have you had any succes on this topic?